# Win Server 2012 R2 - Give user permission to map network drive

Tags: windows-7, permissions, windows-server-2012-r2

How can I adjust group permissions in Computer Management to allow a user to access the `wwwroot` folder from another computer on the network?

As of now, the only way I have been able to give the user permissions is by adding them to the `Administrators` group. What group do I need to add the user to in order to allow them to access, read/write files in the `wwwroot` folder without giving them administrator access?

The user will be accessing it through Windows 7 and/or Windows 10

Comment: The problem here is not share permissions of group policy, but filesystem permissions on c:\inetpub. grant the user access to the folder locally, and then attempt to share it. Share permissions stack on top of disk permissions so a share to a point on disk that the user does not have access to will be inaccessible. the user must be allowed both to the share and to the folder.

Comment: Well, I see that the security settings of the folder have permissions for the `Users` group, and within the `Users` group, our `NET\Domain Users` is a member, and that user is a part of that `Domain Users` group. So shouldn't it work?

Comment: were those permissions propagated to the sub-directories? usually that configuration would not be automatically inherited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the permissions of almost any folder in Windows... just right click and click "share". Follow the sharing wizard and add the user to have read/write permissions... they can then open/map as desired...

Comment: Well I appreciate this, but that just screwed up my webserver.

Comment: Give more detail of the fault rather than a go at someone trying to help you...

Comment: Wasn't having a go, this was on a live site. But whatever it was, when I added the user to permissions I got a 401 Error, so I removed the users permissions then it changed to a 500 error. Turns out that removed permissions to access the website...

Comment: Argh, it seems the sharing wizard overwrites some of the original permissions. There are resources that allow you to re-add the required permissions and get it back up. Google "share wwwroot 401" and there's some resources that can help restore the permissions - sorry! The next method to add users is from the "Security" tab in the folder properties.

Comment: Thanks, yeah got it fixed up. I think I'm done playing around for the day though lol

Comment: You really need to becareful here.  The simple sharing wizard will almost certainly screw up any complex permissions on any pre-existing folder.  Also, when setting up permissions, make sure you setup groups, and set your permissions based on groups, instead of granting them to a specific user.  That way you can easily add or remove people from the group.

Comment: @Zoredache, yes, I was going to add a comment to not let thud be the accepted answer because it clearly isn't.

Comment: @Zoredache thats what I was trying to do. But I guess the only group that allowed those kinds of file permissions was the administrators group.